# Soft question: Reference on sociology of mathematics

Tags: soft-question

Recently, I was reading the article [Manifold Destiny](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2006/08/28/manifold-destiny). It is about the problems of attribution to the solution of the Poincaré Conjecture. Throughout the discussion, the article brings up many interesting points, such as:

> “Politics, power, and control have no legitimate role in our community, and they threaten the integrity of our field,” Phillip Griffiths said.
>
> “It is not people who break ethical standards who are regarded as aliens,” he [Perelman] said. “It is people like me who are isolated.”

These reminded of similar points brought up in the book [The Trouble with Physics by Lee Smolin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trouble_with_Physics). Regarding string theory and the politics within the physics community and how it affects scientific results.

I would like to know if there is a book or articles that focus on such sociological issues inside the mathematics community.

So far, the text that gets the closest to what I would like to know is [Letters to a Young Mathematician by Ian Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letters_to_a_Young_Mathematician). There is a section where the maths community is discussed. Ian Stewart mentions two kinds of approaches: that of the maverick, and that of collaboration; where he emphasises the value of collaboration. Still the discussion is superficial.

**Note:** I did not know where to ask this question. I was hesitant between MSE, MathOverflow, and AcademiaSE. I chose this as the question is specific to mathematics, but not in MOF as it is a very general question. If there is a place where this question would be more appropriate, please let me know. I am glad to post the question there.

Comment: For a slightly narrower version of your question, see [What are good articles/books on the psychology of mathematical research?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297632/what-are-good-articles-books-on-the-psychology-of-mathematical-research)

Answer (score 1):

The prize-winning essay "Manifold Destiny" mentioned in the *question* has an interesting cast of characters where the main protagonists both happen to be first-rate mathematicians.  The essay illustrates how far a person can go in advancing dubious aims by exploiting "politics, power, and control" (as Griffiths put it).

There is a recent case that is similar in the sense that a person goes quite far in obtaining grants, collaborators, publications, international awards, an patents (but is *dissimilar* in the sense that the scientific credentials of the person in question are dubious to say the least).

The case involves Yaroslav Sergeyev and his system, discussed in the following posts: (1) [at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/226277/28128); (2) [at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/122080/72694); (3) [at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2497969/72694); (4) [at EMS SURVEYS IN MATHEMATICAL SCIENCES](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/notice/emss/ed_note.pdf).